# CMD - Display what folder is being searched

Tags: batch-file

This batch files searches for multimedia files but excludes folders with certain keywords (please see code). I was wondering if CMD can show what folder is being scanned so the users will now that it is running.

here is my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d C:\
echo ______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
echo. 
echo This batch file will search for multimedia files in Drive C: but will exclude the folders with the following keywords:
echo. 
echo 1. microsoft
echo 2. windows
echo 3. cisco
echo 4. landesk
echo 5. adobe
echo ______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
echo. 
echo. 
echo. 
echo Searching for MP3...

echo File List > output1.csv
dir /b *.mp3 /s| findstr /v /i "microsoft windows cisco adobe landesk"  >>output1.csv
echo Searching for MP4...
dir /b *.mp4 /s| findstr /v /i "microsoft windows cisco adobe landesk" >>output1.csv
echo Searching for JPG...
dir /b *.jpg /s| findstr /v /i "microsoft windows cisco adobe landesk" >>output1.csv
echo Searching for PNG...
dir /b *.png /s| findstr /v /i "microsoft windows cisco adobe landesk" >>output1.csv
echo Searching for MKV...
dir /b *.mkv /s| findstr /v /i "microsoft windows cisco adobe landesk" >>output1.csv
echo. 
echo. 
echo Done Searching...
Pause
endlocal
```

Comment: Do you know that multiple wildcard patterns can be specified on __DIR__ command line, i.e. `dir *.mp3 *.mp4 *.jpg *.png *.mkv /B /S | findstr /v /i "microsoft windows cisco adobe landesk"  >>output1.csv`?

Comment: @Mofi, No i dont and I will try it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C:` is generally the System drive and has protected locations, I would therefore offer a single line [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy) command, to be run from an Administrator [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) window or from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) 'Run as administrator'.

Here is an example:

```bat
RoboCopy %SystemDrive%\ . *.mp3 *.mp4 *.jpg *.png *.mkv /S /XD Microsoft Windows Cisco LANDesk Adobe /LOG:"%SystemDrive%\output1.csv" /L /XJD /FP /NS /NC /NP /NDL /NJH /NJS
```

*Please note that there will be some leading tabs and/or space characters in that output file, and just because you used a `.csv` extension does not mean that the content will be returned as `C`omma `S`eparated `V`alues.*

You may wish to modify the `RoboCopy` options, to see those and make an informed decision, enter `robocopy /?` at the Command Prompt to read its usage information. You may find it better, for instance to remove the `/NJH` option, so that the log file clearly shows pertinent information related to the search performed.

---

You will note that this does not directly answer your question because, your script is already informing the end user that a search is taking place, where at, and what for. It also informs them when that search is complete. This single command, even if run from [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), should show the log file path to inform the end user of where that information is being saved.